# How to translate "being a"?

Tags: grammar, idiom

I'm aware German doesn't have a gerund like the English language does, so I was just wondering how you could translate "being a" as in "being a vegetarian may cause health problems"?

Would "als" work here?

Comment: *being* -> *to be* -> *zu sein*

Comment: Just for clarification, German does have a Gerund form by making the verb a neuter noun: "sein" ("be") to "das Sein" ("the action of being something or existing"), just for the example here.

Comment: @ em1: you are missing the cause-notion of "being a"

Answer (score 9):

As  @Em1 correctly explained

```
Vegetarier zu sein könnte gesundheitliche Probleme verursachen/ bedingen.
```

oder flüssiger

```
Vegetarier zu sein könnte der Gesundheit abträglich sein / schaden.
```

Comment: These examples are grammatically correct but unidiomatic. Germans don't typically use "zu sein" gerunds. Active verbs sound better: I'd try "Sich an eine vegetarische Diät zu halten..." or "Als Vegetarier zu leben..." .

Comment: I disagree in so far as that your examples are not any better or more common. On the contrary , to me they are more complicated the one of Bummie... If someone wanted to match the succinctness of the English gerund, a German would probably say "Eine vegetarische Ernährung kann zu ... " or more colloquial "Kein Fleisch zu essen...

Comment: As a native speaker, I don't think the use of "zu sein" is unidiomatic. However, I don't like the „könnte“.

I would probably use "Vegetarier zu sein kann der Gesundheit schaden." or "Vegetarier zu sein kann zu gesundheitlichen Problemen führen."

Comment: Noch kompakter: "Vegetarismus kann der Gesundheit schaden" o. "~ kann ungesund sein". Vor allem schmeckt es nicht. ;)

Comment: Colloquially I would drop the "zu".

Answer (score 7):

In your example **"being a vegetarian may cause health problems,"** you'd need to resort to  a different expression, e.g. change the phrase "being a vegetarian" to "to live as a vegetarian" or "life as a vegetarian":

```
a) |Als Vegetarier zu leben| verursacht möglicherweise Gesundheitsprobleme. 

b) |Das Leben als Vegetarier| ruft möglicherweise Gesundheitsprobleme hervor.
```

It's a different thing with e.g. **"being a chef, he knew how to make lasagna,"** where you can indeed use "*Als X*":

```
|Als Koch| wusste er, wie man Lasagne zubereitet.
```

Comment: +1 for the difference between "being a vegetarian" and "being a chef" (or rather the significance of the comma).

Comment: we can bring the examples even closer together:  "Being a vegetarian he knows how to cook tasty stuff with vegetables"... there are different functions of "being a"

Answer (score 0):

Additionally *als* can be used as you actually purposed.

For instance

> Being an office employee, I don't dare to complain about that.

could be like so

> Als Büroangestellter wage ich nicht mich darüber zu beschweren.

Comment: It does not work for the sentence in the question, though.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz right. What I had in mind is the more general question in the title.